# Cant Access PostgreSQL on Google Cloud SQL from NestJS project on Google App Engine

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, nestjs, typeorm

This is my first question in Stack Overflow so please excuse me when my information is lack.

### Issue

I am struggling to connect PostgreSQL on CloudSQL from NestJS on Google App Engine.
When I try to use the application in local environment the program works but when it comes to production in Google App Engine then it does not work.

Since i struggled days, I decided to ask awesome community here.

### My Environment

- Node.js: v10.19.0
- NestJS: 6.10.5
- TypeORM
- PostgreSQL: 11.5.1

### My app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
env: standard

default_expiration: "4d 5h"

env_variables:
  DATABASE_HOST: < public IP for Cloud SQL instance >
  DATABASE_USERNAME: username
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: password
  DATABASE_NAME: databasename
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: "PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_ID:DATABASE_NAME"

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

### Error

```
[Nest] 18   - 02/27/2020, 8:25:46 AM   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)... +34816ms

2020-02-27 08:25:46 default[20200227t163916]  Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.84.188.209:5432      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:
```

### Others Operations

GAE Service Account

Also I added the Cloud SQL Client authority my GAE Service account (something like this service-PROJECT_ID@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com).

I also added package.json as written in below:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x.x"
  },
```

In the typeorm options, I added extra socketpath.

```
extra: {
   socketPath: `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>/`,
            },
```

I do not understand if this option should be set or not (I have tried both).

```
socketPath: `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>/.s.PGSQL.5432

or 

socketPath: `/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

Comment: Why do you need DATABASE_HOST: < public IP for Cloud SQL instance >. Can you please post the code that are you using to connect to sql instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the example provided in GitHub

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/cloudsql_postgresql/app.flexible.yaml

The INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME environment variable does not include the DATABASE_NAME as a parameter.

## e.g. my-awesome-project:us-central1:my-cloud-sql-instance

Maybe this could be causing that the name of the instance is not being resolved for the Proxy.

Comment: Dear Mario-san I have tried to connect database as you mentioned(no need to database name) and could successfully connect.